# How can I create an array from names and values of checkboxes in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Imagine I have an array of selected checkboxes. Each has a value and name that corresponds with a filter.

```html
<input class="filter-item--checkbox" type="checkbox" name="colors" value="blue">
<input class="filter-item--checkbox" type="checkbox" name="colors" value="orange">
<input class="filter-item--checkbox" type="checkbox" name="items" value="chair">
<input class="filter-item--checkbox" type="checkbox" name="items" value="bed">
<input class="filter-item--checkbox" type="checkbox" name="material" value="plastic">
<input class="filter-item--checkbox" type="checkbox" name="material" value="wood">
```

How can I sort these into one array, like below?

```
const filters = [
 'colors': [ 'blue', 'orange'],
 'items': ['chair', 'bed'],
 'material': ['plastic', 'wood'],
]
```

Comment: You may want to put your code into https://jsfiddle.net/ and provide the link to the code in here so that the audience can look at the problem and possibly help you solve it easier.

Comment: The target structure is not valid. The OP might use an object where each entry features the key (e.g. 'colors', 'items', 'material') and the related array of values.

Comment: @PaulMyers ... At SO it is considered to be a nice gesture from the one who got help, to provide some feedback and/or vote on answers and/or accept the answer which was the most helpful in solving the OP's problem.

Comment: @PeterSeliger Well I've already thanked the person, whose help I have used. I need 15 rep points to cast a vote on any answers, so I can't do that yet, otherwise I would have. Anything else?

Comment: @PaulMyers ... Then it was nice if you **accept** (*"... and/or accept the answer"*) Nina's answer. Every answer has an accept link/button next to it; no privileges needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get the elements and build an object of arrays.

```js
const result = {};

for (const { name, value } of document.getElementsByClassName('filter-item--checkbox')) {
    (result[name] ??= []).push(value);
}

console.log(result);
```

```html
<input class="filter-item--checkbox" type="checkbox" name="colors" value="blue">
<input class="filter-item--checkbox" type="checkbox" name="colors" value="orange">
<input class="filter-item--checkbox" type="checkbox" name="items" value="chair">
<input class="filter-item--checkbox" type="checkbox" name="items" value="bed">
<input class="filter-item--checkbox" type="checkbox" name="material" value="plastic">
<input class="filter-item--checkbox" type="checkbox" name="material" value="wood">
```

Answer (score 0):

For the OP's use case, where it was said that a solution should target just checked checkbox controls one could/should utilize the [`FormData` Web-API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData) and its [`entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/entries) method together with a [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) task. Passing a form reference directly into the `FormData` constructor ensures only **active** control data to be part of the form data object. Thus the name/key and value of an unchecked checkbox control gets not reflected by the form data object.

```js
const formData = new FormData(document.forms[0]);
console.log(
  Array
    .from(
      formData.entries()
    )
    .reduce((result, [key, value]) => {

      const groupedValueList = (result[key] ??= []);
      groupedValueList.push(value);

      return result;

    }, {})
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 85%!important; }
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="checkbox" name="colors" value="blue" checked/>
  <input type="checkbox" name="colors" value="orange" checked/>
  <input type="checkbox" name="items" value="chair" checked/>
  <input type="checkbox" name="items" value="bed" checked/>
  <input type="checkbox" name="material" value="plastic" checked/>
  <input type="checkbox" name="material" value="wood" checked/>
</form>
```

In case of collecting all grouped checkbox values regardless of their `checked` state one just needs to change the above approach slightly too ...

```js
console.log(
  Array
    .from(
      document.querySelectorAll('form [type="checkbox"]')
    )
    .reduce((result, { name:key, value }) => {

      const groupedValueList = (result[key] ??= []);
      groupedValueList.push(value);

      return result;

    }, {})
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 85%!important; }
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="checkbox" name="colors" value="blue" checked/>
  <input type="checkbox" name="colors" value="orange"/>
  <input type="checkbox" name="items" value="chair" checked/>
  <input type="checkbox" name="items" value="bed"/>
  <input type="checkbox" name="material" value="plastic" checked/>
  <input type="checkbox" name="material" value="wood"/>
</form>
```